# new file is created instead of copying file

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, nsfilemanager

EDIT: Doesn't look like it's working with the simulator either now.

Some more info, It seems if I install an archived version that did work, then install the one that wont work, right over it, everything works great. but when I delete the archived version, and install the new one, thats when everything stops working.

I was just testing my app on my iPhone, and it was working perfectly, and when I archived it, and installed the ipa on my phone, the database stopped working. no errors occur when you load the database, and like I said before, it was JUST working. I didn't change ANY code. it still works on the simulator, so I know it has to do with the copying of the database. here's the relevant code:

```
dbPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/database.sql", NSHomeDirectory()];
// Get the documents directory
NSFileManager *fmngr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database.sql" ofType:nil];
NSError *error;
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"didLaunchFirstTime"])
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"didLaunchFirstTime"];
    [fmngr removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/database.sql", NSHomeDirectory()] error:&error];

    if(![fmngr copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/database.sql", NSHomeDirectory()] error:&error])
    {
        // handle the error
        NSLog(@"Error creating the database: %@", [error description]);

    }
}
```

My query looks like this, because I'm using FMDB to query the database. It's in a separate method called when the user presses the search button.

```
FMResultSet *s = [db executeQueryWithFormat:@"SELECT Gurmukhi, ShabadID, FirstLetterStr FROM Shabad WHERE FirstLetterStr LIKE %@", searchString];
```

I also unzipped the ipa to check if the database wasn't blank, and it isn't. I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Have you tried removing the app from the device and reinstalling it again?

Comment: @SPVarma yeah, even restarted my phone

Comment: @SPVarma Actually, something interesting. I removed the application from the simulator this time, and when it went to build, it's doing the same thing as my iPhone. did the new ios6 beta change anything with directories?

Comment: @Mukhi: Where are you implementing this code? I hope it is in - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator ?

Comment: @mvb no.. it's just in the viewDidLoad method. it was working before, is there any specific reason it needs to be there?

Comment: May be if you could show some more code where you are actually querying the database, I can comment. Are you using Core Data as the interface?

Comment: @mvb no, I'm using a wrapper, FMDB let me edit the post with the code

Comment: You can also profile your application with the I/O Activity instrument to see if there is problem opening the database.

Comment: @mvb actually I don't know what's going on, but I used an archived version of my app, installed it, then built the app using xcode, and everything works. I don't know why, but if I delete the app altogether, likely because it's getting rid of the database, and then reinstall, it stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be hardcoding directory paths in your app - Apple provides functions to get them:

When you want to find the file in your bundle, you get it this way:

NSString *dbPathOld = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"database" ofType:@"sql"];

Now you have a path to the sql file you provided with your app.

When you want to copy it, you use this code:

NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *dbPathNew = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"database.sql"];

Other comments:

1) Why not use the NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];?

2) With your standard defaults, you are registering them in an initialize method in your app  delegate? You are synchronizing them after you update values (so in fact "didLaunchFirstTime" is set the second time)? You might want to add a log message so you can  know for sure.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong, but none of that code is working for me. Even if I try to read the database from the read-only location it's normally in, in this case dbPathOld, it doesn't even give me the error that it can't be opened.

Comment: So did you test that the file in fact is there? Spelling exactly correct (capitalization etc)? Did you look in app bundle to verify its there (in an ipa?). You can use the file manager to test for existence, to verify readability, etc. Lots of people do what you want to do so its something about your app.

Comment: I know the file is there, and that it is copied, but I can't tell what's in the copied file. the only thing I can think of is that the copied file is blank for some reason. And yes I realize a lot of people do it, and it was JUST working for me. but when I deleted the old app and installed the new one, it didn't work, but when I installed the new one over the old one, it works fine. which means it's something to do with the copied version, right?

Comment: You have multiple things going on - you want to copy the file if its the first time your app runs, and you want Core Data to open that file after its moved (but not before). Are you logging all of this so you know the order of operations is correct? Instead of using a flag in defaults, why not just test for the copied file in the documents folder? If its there you already copied it - if its not there you need to copy it. It almost sounds like order is wrong, you do copy it, but Core Data tried to open it too soon. Second launch, file is found, so its seems like magic.

Comment: Well for some reason the file exists to begin with, but that file is blank. So I need to check if it's the first time it's been run, if it is, I remove the file there, copy the correct file, and at the end of it all, open the database with the path to the file.

Comment: The file cannot just appear on its own. It sounds to me like it gets created by your code creating a persistent storage of the name BEFORE the file gets copied - a race condition of sorts - thus my suggestion to add log messages. Or there is some explanation as to how that file got created in your documents folder - hmmm - using iCloud?

Comment: No, not using iCloud. I tried one more thing, it works in the simulator if I use the directory to where the original file is located. Obviously this can't work for the iPhone, but why does it work with the original file and not the one that is copied into the project?  EDIT: actually I just checked and it just doesn't work with any of the dynamic directories, e.g. dbPathNew or dbPathOld

Comment: I fixed it, and it's such a stupid fix... I didn't put the sql file in the folder with all the other header and implementation files. didn't need it there before, but apparently you do now.

Comment: So let me get this - the .sql file was included in your project, but was not in a folder inside your project? That just doesn't sound like a bug. If you look at your Build Phase "copy bundle resources", it should be able to copy the file from anywhere (as long as you had it included in your Target.) You must have "fixed" something else.

Comment: Nope, did nothing else. Only this is that the resource is read-only now, but that's fine for hat I need, as the database shouldn't be updated anyway.